# How to update the listview in android when new item is inserted

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask, scroll, listener

i'm having the asynctask which populate the listview from the localhost reponses from the database . how to update the listview only when the new item is added.I have used Timers to update the listview but it does not let me scroll up as it keeps force-pushing the scrollbar to the bottom.

```
class MessageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<String>> {

             private final HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();

            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
            @Override
            protected List<String> doInBackground(String... params) {

                String output = "";
               for(String out:params){
                   list.removeAll(list);
                   //Collections.reverse(list);
                     try{
                     HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(out);
                     ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                     output = Client.execute(httpget, responseHandler);

                       try {


                        JSONObject jObject= new JSONObject(output);
                        JSONArray menuObject = new JSONArray(jObject.getString("response"));   

                        //int len=menuObject.length();


                        //HashMap<String,ArrayList> map = new HashMap<String,ArrayList>();

                     for (int i = menuObject.length()-1; i>=0; i--)
                      {

                         list.add(menuObject.getJSONObject(i).getString("fk_username_c").toString()+" "+menuObject.getJSONObject(i).getString("message_c").toString());     
                        // if(i==len){
                        // newtc=menuObject.getJSONObject(i).getString("timestamp_c").toString();
                         //}
                     }
                     /* if(oldtc==null){
                          oldtc=newtc;
                      }if
                      else{


                      }*/
                      adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(ChatActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

                       } catch (JSONException e) {
                           Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data ");
                       }
                     }catch(Exception e){
                         Log.i("Animation", "Thread  exception " );
                     }
               }

              return list;

            }

      @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    @Override      
    protected void onPostExecute(List<String> list) {


            //if(!oldtc.equals(newtc)){       
              listview.setAdapter(adapter);
          adapter.clear();
          listview.clearTextFilter();
          adapter.addAll(list);
          adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            //}


    }
     }
```

please help me how to update the listview only the new data is inserted in database

Comment: Just call the setAdapter method once again.

Comment: Maintain List Size in Temporary Variable and after new data Arrives Just Compare size in temporary variable with New list size if they are not equal then call adapter.NotifyDatasetChanged() :)

Answer (score 2):

When new item is added just call `adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: i used the adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() in my code, i excepting how to update the listview only when the data is inserted

Answer (score 0):

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `setAdapter` after `addAll`

```
      adapter.clear();
      listview.clearTextFilter();
      adapter.addAll(list);
      listview.setAdapter(adapter);
      adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use broadcasting in which whenever the new response come from server, broadcast this response and register broadcast reciever in that activity in which you want to update listview.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to clear the adapter array.
Just update the adapter array (adding or removing items) and then call `.notifyDataSetChanged()`